# Converting pseudocode to implementation as similar as possible

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, computer-science

When I study algorithms from a textbook, usually the algorithm being in pseudocode is as generic as possible.

An example is that in order to simplify checks or boundary cases or when to stop a loop the occusionally -/+ infinity is being used (as a simplification of course).

For example:

`current-sum=`[image]

```
total-sum=0  
for i=x downto low  
 total-sum=total-sum+A[i]  
     if(total-sum > current-sum)  //so that in first iteration we will enter the if statement
```

`etc`

Ok, the minus infinity can be replaced when implementing the algorithm in a programming language with a value not expected in our domain of problem.

I was wondering though if there is a more generic way/trick to represent this when implementing the algorithm in a concrete programming language, for example Java, than doing:
e.g.
`current-sum = -1;`
or
`current-sum = -10000;`

where for instance these values could later actually become valid as domain values.

Comment: I don't understand what the pseudo code is doing or why.  This makes it difficult to translate.

Comment: The pseudocode is part of the algorithm for computing the max subarray problem. In this part it calculates sums in the array and uses -infinity as a starting point.If you think it makes sense I can post more of the pseudocode

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering though if there is a more generic way/trick to represent this when implementing the algorithm in a concrete programming language

In general no.  There is no way to represent "minus infinity" as an integer that will always work.  The smallest possible integer value (in Java `Integer.MIN_VALUE`) is often used.  But you need to look at the specific algorithm to understand if this solution works.

Hence there is no general / generic solution.

---

In your example `Integer.MIN_VALUE` can be used in place of "minus infinity".  However,
if an algorithm requires you to use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as an actual value, then you can't *also* use it as a "no value" marker.  Another case where `Integer.MIN_VALUE` doesn't work as a proxy for "minus infinity" is when you use it to do arithmetic.  (`Integer.MIN_VALUE + x == Integer.MIN_VALUE` only holds for `x == 0`.)

Comment: +1 for expanded treatment of generic problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) which is the smallest 32-bit representable value (-2^31).

Alternatively, if this could actually be a valid value in your problem, you could extend to 64 bits and just use `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

And finally, there's always the option of `boolean firstTime = true;` which you `||` against your `if` condition the first time around, and immediately set it to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int current_sum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

This gives current_sum the minimum value an int can have, -(2^31).

Answer (score 1):

Normally you are representing infinity with the maximum that can fit in your datatype.

For example if you have +inifity, you can use `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
Same with -infinity, you can use `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

It's the same with other datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` bad solutions because in some cases they can become values in your domain. More carefully using `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`.

For example `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY + 2 = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`

Comment: That's interesting, I never knew about that property. Cool.